# Los elementos de una colección de un objeto Entity "disminuyen" al recorrerla

Tags: c#, entity-framework

En mi aplicación, que usa Entity Framework, estoy intentando **clonar** registros. 
De hecho, en parte ya lo logré (siguiendo las guías del post [Entity Framework 6: Clone object except ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720803/entity-framework-6-clone-object-except-id) de SO).

Este es un *ejemplo* de cómo está armada mi Entidad (datos inventados):
(***Editada** con más detalles y ejemplos*)

```
/** Estructura */
Modelo                                    // Modelo Entity

Modelo.Construccion                       // Entidad 1 
Modelo.Construccion.ConstrId              // PK (auto generado)
Modelo.Construccion.Nombre                // Una propiedad de "Construccion"

Modelo.Material                           // Entidad 2 
Modelo.Material.MatId                     // PK (auto generado)
Modelo.Material.Nombre                    // Una propiedad de "Material"

Modelo.Construccion.MaterialConstruccion              // Una colección de entidades "Modelo.Material" de "Construccion"
Modelo.Construccion.MaterialConstruccion[n].Id        // PK (auto generado)
Modelo.Construccion.MaterialConstruccion[n].ConstrId  // FK Construccion
Modelo.Construccion.MaterialConstruccion[n].MatId     // FK Material


/** Datos Ejemplo "Construccion" */
--------- --------------
ConstrId  Nombre
--------- --------------
1         Casa Tipo A

/** Datos Ejemplo "Material" */
------- -------------
MatId   Nombre
------- -------------
A       Cemento
B       Viga
C       Cerámico
D       Ventana

/** Datos Ejemplo "Materiales de Construccion" */
------- ------- ---------
Id      MatId   ConstrId
------- ------- ---------
1       A       1
2       B       1
3       C       1
4       D       1
```

Como dije, usando el método del post en inglés de SO, logré clonar los datos principales de "Construccion": se crea
 un nuevo registro con los mismos datos del original, cambiando sólo el Identificador (en este ejemplo, se auto genera un nuevo valor de `ConstrId`).
En mi código, primero realizo la *clonación* de la "cabecera" (los datos de `Construccion`), y tras que finaliza con éxito,
 y teniendo ya el nuevo `ConstrId`...

```
/** Datos Ejemplo "Construccion": OK */
--------- --------------
ConstrId  Nombre
--------- --------------
1         Casa Tipo A    // El original
2         Casa Tipo A    // El clon
```

...inicio la *clonación* de la colección relacionada (los "Materiales de Construccion")...
El problema surge allí, cuando intento clonar dicha colección relacionada (en el ejemplo, cuando intento clonar los
 "Materiales de Construcción" en la nueva entidad `ConstrId = 2`): al recorrer los elementos de la colección de `ConstrId = 1`, no sé por qué,
 pero el `Count` de la misma va decreciendo...

Cuando uso este ciclo `for`, me arroja Excepción y:
1) Me clona los registros saltando uno por medio, partiendo en el primero.
2) Si la colección tiene 1 solo elemento, no me clona nada.

```
// Si Cabecera de "Construccion" fue clonada con exito,
// tenemos un nuevo Identificador:
if (nuevoConstrId > 0)
{
  try
  {
    using (Modelo.Entities dataModel = new Modelo.Entities())
    {
      // Acceso a Entidad Original:
      Modelo.Construccion construccionOriginal = dataModel.Construccion.Find(constrId);
      // Acceso a Entidad Clonada:
      Modelo.Construccion construccionClonada = dataModel.Construccion.Find(nuevoConstrId);

      if (construccionClonada != null
          && construccionOriginal != null)
      {
        // Si la Entidad Original tiene "Materiales de Construccion":
        if (construccionOriginal.MaterialConstruccion.Count > 0)
        {
          int i;
          int filasAfectadas = 0;
          int cantidadMateriales = construccionOriginal.MaterialConstruccion.Count;

          for (i = 0; i < cantidadMateriales; i++)
          {
            // Obtiene el ID de cada "Material de Construccion", para asi poder
            // acceder a sus datos, los cuales vamos a clonar:
            long Id = construccionOriginal.MaterialConstruccion.ElementAt(i).Id;

            if (Id > 0)
            {
              // Instancia un nuevo objeto "MaterialConstruccion"
              Modelo.MaterialConstruccion materialConstr = dataModel.MaterialConstruccion.Find(Id);

              if materialConstr != null)
              {
                // Lo unico que cambia entre el objeto original y el nuevo,
                // es su relacion con "Construccion": este nuevo Material
                // va a pertenecer a nuevoConstrId.
                materialConstr.ConstrId = nuevoConstrId;

                // Agrega el objeto al contexto:
                dataModel.MaterialConstruccion.Add(materialConstr);
                filasAfectadas += dataModel.SaveChanges();
              }
            }
          }

          if (filasAfectadas == construccionOriginal.MaterialConstruccion.Count)
          {
            // "Materiales Clonados Exitosamente"
          }
          else
          {
            // "Materiales Clonados Parcialmente"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // ex.Message
  }
}
```

La Excepción es:

> El argumento especificado está fuera del intervalo de valores válidos.
>   Nombre del parámetro: index.

Y es lógico, pues, como les decía, los elementos van "desapareciendo" de la colección a medida que la recorro, 
por lo que cuando quiere ingresar por ejemplo al elemento en la posición `4`, ya no puede, porque el `Count` ha disminuido.

En el caso de cuando usé `foreach` en vez de `for`:
1) Me clona sólo el primer elemento, da lo mismo la cantidad de elementos.

```
foreach (Modelo.MaterialConstruccion material in construccionOriginal.MaterialConstruccion)
{
  material.ConstruccionId = nuevoConstrId;
  dataModel.MaterialConstruccion.Add(material);
  dataModel.Entry(material).State = EntityState.Added; // con o sin esto, da igual
  filasAfectadas += dataModel.SaveChanges();
}
```

La Excepción que salta es:

> Colección modificada; puede que no se ejecute la operación de enumeración.

Esto es un ejemplo de lo que espero:

```
/** Datos Ejemplo "Materiales de Construccion" */
------- ------- ---------
Id      MatId   ConstrId
------- ------- ---------
1       A       1
2       B       1
3       C       1
4       D       1
1       A       2
2       B       2
3       C       2
4       D       2
```

Esto es lo que obtengo al usar `for`:

```
/** Datos Ejemplo "Materiales de Construccion" */
------- ------- ---------
Id      MatId   ConstrId
------- ------- ---------
1       A       1
2       B       1
3       C       1
4       D       1
1       A       2
3       C       2
```

Esto es lo que obtengo al usar `foreach`:

```
/** Datos Ejemplo "Materiales de Construccion" */
------- ------- ---------
Id      MatId   ConstrId
------- ------- ---------
1       A       1
2       B       1
3       C       1
4       D       1
1       A       2
```

Ya hice mi búsqueda googleana, y no encontré luces sobre el asunto :(

La **pregunta** entonces es: ¿A qué se debe este comportamiento de la Colección, al recorrerla en un ciclo?
Y la pregunta derivada es: ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de recorrer la Colección?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Edité mi pregunta, con más detalles y especificaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que te está sucediendo es que en lugar de "clonar" los materiales los estás transfiriendo de una construcción a otra por error.

Revisando la siguiente parte de tu código:

```
//Obtienes un material de la construcción original
Modelo.MaterialConstruccion material = dataModel.MaterialConstruccion.Find(matId);

if (material != null)
{
   //Actualizas su ConstruccionId, sigue siendo el mismo registro en la base de datos
   material.ConstruccionId = nuevoConstrId;
   dataModel.MaterialConstruccion.Add(material);
   filasAfectadas += dataModel.SaveChanges();
}
```

Cuando das la orden de guardar entityFramework detecta que el objeto ya tiene una llave primaria y por tanto actualiza el registro en lugar de generar uno nuevo. La recomendación sería crear un nuevo objeto y pasar la información a ese para después guardarlo.

```
//Obtienes un material de la construcción original
Modelo.MaterialConstruccion material = dataModel.MaterialConstruccion.Find(matId);

if (material != null)
{
   var nuevoMaterial = new Modelo.MaterialConstruccion();
   /*
     Estableces el valor de sus propiedades
   */
   nuevoMaterial.ConstruccionId = nuevoConstrId;
   dataModel.MaterialConstruccion.Add(nuevoMaterial);
   filasAfectadas += dataModel.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder :) Te aclaro: siguiendo el ejemplo, el objeto `MaterialConstruccion` tiene su propio identificador (`Id`), que se autogenera al hacer el `Add()` a la colección de "Materiales de Construcción" (edité la pregunta para aclarar eso). Esta sintaxis de clonación se ve rara, pero como decían en el post de SO en inglés que cité, sí funciona. Y como dije al principio de mi pregunta, funciona cuando hago la clonación de la entidad padre... En fin, si demoro mucho en solucionar este problema, lo haré usando tu sugerencia. Gracias de nuevo ;)

Comment: Al final, me rendí (al tiempo), y apliqué una solución que se basa en la que me dijiste. Lo escribiré como respuesta, aunque la verdad, _no responde mi pregunta_, pero soluciona el problema de la "clonación fallida". Gracias otra vez ;)

Answer (score 0):

Al fin, "solucioné" el problema de la clonación fallida, pero aún no sé por qué se produce esta disminución de elementos al recorrerlos en el ciclo que clona los objetos. Escribiré esta respuesta, más que nada para que me quede de ayuda memoria, pero no es la "correcta", pues no responde a mi pregunta.

Analizando la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/159335/78037) de @AarónBC, se me ocurrió que algo de verdad había en ella, pensando en que Entity cree que estoy "actualizando" los registros, y por eso se "vuelve loco" al intentar modificar un elemento del mismo ciclo que recorre (algo relacionado con la recursividad), aun cuando al final, efectivamente los "agrega" como nuevos, y los originales quedan intactos.

Por eso, para que no se vuelva loquito, decidí hacer un mix entre lo que me sugirió @AarónBC y lo que ya tenía, y funcionó perfecto: lo único que me molesta es tener que setear cada una de las propiedades del nuevo objeto, cuando la idea era que se copiara por sí solo (en el ejemplo de aquí es sólo una propiedad, pero en mi entidad original son muchas más).

```
foreach (Modelo.MaterialConstruccion material in construccionOriginal.MaterialConstruccion)
{
  Modelo.MaterialConstruccion nuevoMaterial = new Modelo.MaterialConstruccion();
  nuevoMaterial.ConstrId = nuevoConstrId;
  nuevoMaterial.MatId = material.MatId;
  dataModel.MaterialConstruccion.Add(nuevoMaterial);
  filasAfectadas += dataModel.SaveChanges();
}
```